# Animation when downloading the program

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here I can not figure out the animation. It is necessary to implement animation when loading a program, as well as animated transitions of states of a single screen, how can I implement this help?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EAn5.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple loading animation. Is it what you need：

custom a **ShowLoading.cs** interface:

```
public interface ShowLoading
{
    void Show();
    void Hide();
}
```

then in **.Android MainActivity.cs** implements the interface:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(MainActivity))]
namespace App18.Droid
{
[Activity(Label = "App18", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity,ShowLoading
{
    private  static Dialog _dialog;
    public void Hide()
    {
        _dialog.Dismiss();

    }

    public void Show()
    {
        _dialog.Show();
    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());
        init();
    }

    private void init()
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.From(this).Inflate(Resource.Layout.loading_layout,null);
        _dialog = new Dialog(this);
        _dialog.RequestWindowFeature((int)WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
        _dialog.SetCancelable(false);
        _dialog.SetContentView(view);
    }
}
```

}

**loading_layout.axml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/frame"
 >

  <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/loading"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent = "true"
    android:indeterminateBehavior="repeat"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/loading" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**loading.xml** (in **Resources/drawable**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:drawable="@drawable/loadingicon"
             android:fromDegrees="0.0"
             android:pivotX="50.0%"
             android:pivotY="50.0%"
             android:toDegrees="360.0" />
```

you could in your page call it by **DependencyService**,like this:

```
//show the loadig animation
DependencyService.Get<ShowLoading>().Show();

//hide it
DependencyService.Get<ShowLoading>().Hide();
```

Comment: It needs to be implemented on Xamarin and not on Java

Comment: i have updatee the answer which in Xamarin.Forms,you could implement it by DependencyService

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with Xamarin, have a look at [SkiaSharp](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/basics/animation). You can create vector graphics and animate them quite easily.

Comment: If you just want something like this, you can look at how to rotate controls in XAML: https://github.com/xamarin/docs-archive/tree/master/Recipes/xamarin-forms/Controls/rotation

Comment: No, I do not need to launch a boot animation such as a photo at startup https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EAn5.jpg